# Is statically typed nodeJS possible? i.e. TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am looking to adopt NodeJS as a server language for a project. However, I am concerned with Javascript as a programming language and am also concerned the lack of type checking of Javascript.

Is there a way to introduce static typing in NodeJS? I have read about TypeScript. However, I am not sure how popular and well supported typeScript is.

For example, there are only 1400 questions on TypeScript on Stackoverflow.

Can anyone speak about TypeScript in production or any optional static typing for NodeJS?

Comment: Dynamic typing is a strength of JavaScript. If you want static typing on your server-side code you should be using Java or C#.

Comment: Or NodeJS with TypeScript :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use TypeScript to create node applications. There are several related node type definitions to assist with this at https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped. These definitions are required for the tsc compiler to understand what your node-specific code is trying to do. Depending on your TS editor, they can also be used to provide intellisense while editing.

Here's a recent article that discusses how prevalent TypeScript is these days: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/10/17/typescript-and-the-road-to-1-0.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to introduce static typing in NodeJS?

There's a Node module for Typescript, instructions on [the "get it" page](http://www.typescriptlang.org/#Download) on the Typescript site:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Then you compile your Typescript (.ts) files to JavaScript:

```
tsc helloworld.ts
```

Comment: We're attacking the question from different angles.. Wonder who will win. :)

Comment: @AlexDresko: :-) I like your direction, +1